How to send multiple requests at once by only 1 Thread in Jmeter
I'm new to JMeter, and I want to create a JMeter script for the below scenario.

Thread count - 1
Requests count - 50

Here the requirement is to invoke all these 50 requests by using only one Thread within 1s. In other words, all these 50 requests should be invoked at once by the 1 Thread once I click the "Start" button of JMeter.
Below is the JMeter Thread Group I created for this scenario.

But this did not work as I expected.
Please can anyone let me know how to achieve this?
Thanks!

You can execute 50 requests in 1 second only if response time is 20 ms or less.
If you want to keep the number of threads in Thread Group as 1 it's possible to kick off extra threads i.e. to simulate AJAX requests using Parallel Controller, but it won't be "using only one Thread", as many threads as there are requests under the Parallel Controller will be spawned.
Normally if you want to run X requests at exactly the same moment you should set the number of threads in Thread Group to X and use Synchronizing Timer setting the "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" to X as well.
